# access denied when cloning local git from Jenkins

Tags: git, deployment, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins on my local linux machine.
I've got a local git repository, that's also using bitbucket as its origin.

I'm attempting to get Jenkins to build from the local git repository, but every time it builds, it gets the following error:

```
Started by user Hippyjim 
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Staging
Checkout:Staging / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Staging - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@15c0729
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:Staging / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Staging - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@15c0729
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from /home/hippyjim/PhpstormProjects/myRepo/.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git fetch -t /home/hippyjim/PhpstormProjects/myRepo/.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Command "git fetch -t /home/hippyjim/PhpstormProjects/myRepo/.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 255: error: cannot open    .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

If I run the clone command it gives in the error message, it works fine. I just need Jenkins to pick up the changes on this local machine to be able to deploy my code. I'm totally stuck here - anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What user is Jenkins running as?  And it's cloning (and fetching) from /home/hippyjim/PhpstormProjects/myRepo to someplace else to do the build?

Comment: Yes, agreed the "Permission denied" error suggests it's a user access issue

Comment: Thanks to user37078 and Mark O'Connor - it *was* a permission problem.

I was attempting to have my jenkins build clone from my local (non-bare) copy of the repo, instead of cloning from bitbucket. As that's in a folder that the Jenkins user doesn't have access to, it was failing. To complicate matters I'd cloned the repo myself, so it had a copy of the repo in the workspace, that it couldn't access.

I cleaned the workspace, and let it clone from bitbucket, and all is well.

If one of you guys wants to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Reminder: guys - I can't accept an answer on this question unless there's actually an answer

Comment: Please close this question as it's already answered!

Comment: Really wanted to accept an answer, but there isn't one. None of the reasons to close a question apply. How should I deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Combining answers from  user37078 and Mark O'Connor:

- What user is Jenkins running as?
- Is it cloning (and/or fetching) from /home/hippyjim/PhpstormProjects/myRepo to someplace else to do the build?
- **"Permission denied" error suggests it's a user access issue**